# c program security_getenforce() not found

Tags: c, gcc, header-files, libvirt, selinux

I am trying to gcc my library with another static library and I get this error while runtime

```
 undefined symbol: security_getenforce
```

I am thinking this is related to selinux, not sure though... how do I resolve this?

Thanks,
Vik.

Comment: A "runtime" error? Are you sure? And are you sure that all includes and libraries are included/linked properly?

Comment: @deviantfan I know I am missing some libraries, but what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, use -lselinux as the flag to resolve the issue and load the necessary libraries.